# Gravar JSON em objeto Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api

Tenho uma API em php que retorna dados assim:

```
{"status":"sucesso","dados":[{"id":"1","nome":"Nome do Usuario","etc..":"etc.."},{"id":"2","nome":"Nome do Usuario","etc..":"etc.."}]}
```

Preciso ler e gravar 2 de todos os dados (id e nome) em um objeto, mas não entendi muito bem a parte de como gravar os dados, até agora tenho isso:

```
//Pesquisa o Json

$.getJSON('http://192.168.0.106/teste/SimpleBook/api/v1/Mostrar/Usuarios/', function(data) {
    if (!data.error) {
        var geraldata = data['dados'];

        var data = [];
        for (var i = geraldata.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            data.push ({
                id: data['dados'][i]['id'],
                text: data['dados'][i]['name']
            });
        }
    } else {
        alert(data.msg)
    }
});
```

O resultado esperado seria algo assim:

```
// Resultado esperado
var data = [{
    id: 0,
    text: 'Nome do Usuario'
}, {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Nome do Usuario'
}];
```

Comment: O formato do seu retorno não é válido!

Comment: Qual seria o formato correto para retorno?

Comment: No formato que inseriu na pergunta esta vindo objeto dentro de objeto **{ {**"id": "01" .... e isso não é uma sintaxe válida, o certo seria um array e dentro dele os objetos.

Comment: Ahnn sim desculpa, acabei de corrigir o exemplo.. Esta parte esta valida, a minha dificulldade é em gravar os dados mesmo

Comment: E você quer gravar onde? Banco de dados, arquivo, etc.
No seu script você já está lendo (atenção ao nome do atributo "nome" que está como "name")

Comment: So preciso gravar em uma variavel o retorno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode utilizar o método [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para mapear cada objeto e as suas propriedades, aí é só armazenar os valores em um **array**:

```js
let retorno = {"status":"sucesso","dados":[{"id":"1","nome":"Nome do Usuario","etc..":"etc.."},{"id":"2","nome":"Nome do Usuario","etc..":"etc.."}]};

let dadosFormatados = [];

retorno.dados.map(_dados => dadosFormatados.push({
    id: _dados.id,
    nome: _dados.nome
}))

console.log(dadosFormatados)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você esvazia o vetor `data` que contém os dados vindos da sua API depois de passar apenas a propriedade `Dados` para uma outra variável. No loop, o programa tenta ler a propriedade que não existe mais do vetor `data` que está vazio:

```
var geraldata = data['dados'];    // Passa somente a propriedade Dados para a outra variável

var data = [];    // Esvazia o vetor que tinha o retorno da API
for (var i = geraldata.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    data.push ({
        id: data['dados'][i]['id'],    // Tenta ler o vetor vazio 
        text: data['dados'][i]['name']
    });
}
```

---

Considerando que o retorno da sua API é esse mesmo indicado, ou seja, as propriedades são `Dados` e `nome` e não `dados` e `name`, uma solução pode ser:

```
var dados_da_api = []

for (var i = data['Dados'].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    dados_da_api.push ({
        id: data['Dados'][i]['id'],     
        text: data['Dados'][i]['nome']
    });
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado! Só não consigo usar a variavel fora do if, diz que ela não foi definida.. Como faço pra passa a variavel dados_da_api pra fora do if?

Comment: Você pode declarar a variável fora do if que ela vai poder ser acessada e modificada de dentro do if ;)